# Probability of lottery

Tags: probability

> In a lottery every week, 2,000,000 tickets are sold for \$1 apiece.
> Say 4000 of these tickets pay off \$30 each, 500 pay off \$800 each,
> and one ticket pays off \$1,200,000, and no ticket pays off more than
> one prize.
>
> (a) What is the expected value of the winning amount for a player with
> a single ticket?
>
> (b) What is the expected value of the winning amount for a player with
> five tickets?

For (a), I did that.
[image]

For (b), since we can select more than one ticket, how can I find the probability?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the list of winnings:
1995499 tickets that yield 0 dollars,
4000 tickets that yield 30 dollars,
500 tickets that yield 800 dollars, and
1 ticket that yields 1,200,000 dollars.

The expected winnings is the average of the sums of 5 elements from the list of winnings. So, each value is essentially added ${1999999 \choose 4}$.

We have to consider ${2000000 \choose 5}$ cases.

If you let S be the sum of all the elements in that list, we have that the average sum of any 5 tickets is $\frac{{1999999 \choose 4} \cdot S}{{2000000 \choose 5}}$ which just simplifies to 5 $\cdot$ $\frac{S}{2000000}$. Since $\frac{S}{2000000}$ is the answer from (a), your answer for part (b) is 5 $\cdot$ 0.86 = **4.3**.

Comment: But there is only one ticket that pays off $1,200,000. I don't think we can easily multiply 5.

Comment: Consider a simpler case: look at the list 1, 2, 3, 4, 100. The expected value you draw is 110/5 = 22. For this example assume you draw 3 numbers. Your expected sum would be [(1 + 2 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 4) + (1 + 2 + 100) + (1 + 3 + 4) + ... + (3 + 4 + 100)] / (number of ways you choose 3 numbers from five numbers). For the numerator you are adding the first element 4 choose 2 times, since you need to choose the other 2 numbers from the remaining 4. So your expected value is (1 +  2 + 3 + 4 + 100) * (4 C 2) / (5 C 3) = 110/5 * 3 = 22 * 3 = 66.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ denote the winnings from the $i^{\text{th}}$ ticket purchased.

Although $X_1,...,X_5$ aren't independent, they certainly are identically distributed and share the common pmf $$p(30)=0.002 \\p(800)=0.00025 \\ p(1200000)=0.0000005\\ p(0)=0.9977495$$ You're trying to find $\mathbb{E}(X_1+\dots +X_5)$ which by linearity of expectation is $5\times 0.86$